# Why a Technical Role user cannot login developer.apple.com?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We have created a user ID on iTunesConnect as a Technical Role. However, there is an error when logging in: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

[image]

The Technical Role ID can login https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ without any problem.

Is it a limitation of the Technical Role itself? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since account are not shared between iTunnesConnect and the Apple Developers centre you will also need to add the account to de Apple Developers account.

Go to the Members Center and just invite the user.